# How do I avoid AngularJS in inline javascript calls?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and MV* patterns in javascript. I've been playing around with AngularJS on a project recently and I was curious as to how I could avoid a situation where I am doing things like `<a ng-click="doSomething()"></a>`? I really don't like my javascript to be in my HTML. I want to be able to control the javascript from the javascript files rather than from the HTML files. Is there a better way to handle this type of stuff along the lines of something how I can specify a class or an id that is supposed to have the behavior associated with it in AngularJS?

Comment: You are looking at AngularJS from the perspective of unobtrusive javascript, which restrains you from viewing the complete picture. Here is a comment from Cary Landholt on the AngularJS mailing list, in which he explains how one should see AngularJS. [Link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/kqZDVSUlkd0/sge6KsaaKQAJ)

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate your own behavior using directives and setup bindings for events on elements to call a function if you want to wrap up a behavior (I believe I read that Ben Nadel an AngularJS blogger does... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2446-Using-Controllers-In-Directives-In-AngularJS.htm).

As is stated in the comment though I personally don't find it to be an issue, if I was on a larger team I could potentially see the desire to leave the binding up to a javascript developer and not have the HTML developer worry about those details and use directives only but seeing as how I write both parts I don't have any issue.

> Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks. During DOM compilation
>   directives are matched against the HTML and executed. This allows
>   directives to **register behavior**, or transform the DOM.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

http://jsfiddle.net/pCA2g/1/

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div clickable>Click me</div>
    <button clickable>Click me</button>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).directive("clickable", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
            iElem.bind("click", function() {
                alert("holy guacamole");
            });
        }
    }
});
```